# CSS Button Borders Not Working In Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a simple website, which contains a button with a link that is styled with CSS.

```
<div id="contact_button">
    <a href="mailto:contact@fakemail.com" class="button">CONTACT</a>
</div>
```

The border displays just fine on IE and Firefox, but is not displaying properly on Chrome (mobile or desktop). Any thoughts?

```
a.button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;

  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;

  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 143px;
  display: block;

  background-color: #FFF; /* White */
  border: 2px solid black;
  color: #000;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

a.button:hover {
  background-color: #000; /* Black */
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the style `-webkit-appearance: button;` from selector `a.button`, I see the same output (white background and 2px-width black border) both in Chrome and in Firefox.